# When crafting the new armor recipes introduced in 1.0.7, what is the best plan to use for each slot?

Tags: diablo-iii

There are different stat affixes that affect the maximum stat attribute roll for each armor piece.

If we look at all the possible affixes for the Strength stat:

"**Ruthless**" (max +100 Vit and Str) and "**of War**" (max +200 Str, see affix Str 16 on "*Strength [Amulet, Axe, Belt, Bow, Ceremonial Knife, Dagger, Fist Weapon, FollowerSpecial, Hand Crossbow, Mace, Mighty Weapon, Offhand, Shoulders, Spear, Sword, Wand]*") are the best [affixes](http://diablonut.incgamers.com/affixes/?c=adventure-and-stats&l=63&u=70#strength), resulting in a total of *300 Strength* and *100 Vitality* on a perfect roll for a rare iLvl 63 shoulder.

Therefore it would be optimal to craft the **[Archon Spaulders of Vitality](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/archon-spaulders-of-vitality)** for a Barbarian, than a perfect **[Archon Spaulders of Strength](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/archon-spaulders-of-strength)** would roll:

**330 Strength** and **200 Vitality**,

but a perfect **Archon Spaulders of Vitality** would roll for:

**300 Strength** and **330 Vitality**.

However the maximum possible stat affix for **Dexterity** and **Intelligence** armor is **+200** for their respective stats.

For Intelligence, it's "**Illustrious**" (max +100 Int and Vit) and "**of Far Sight**" (max +100 Int).

For Dexterity, it's "**Valiant**" (max +100 Dex and Vit) and "**of Pain**" (max +100 Int).

So it makes more sense for a Barbarian to craft Vitality shoulders over Strength shoulders, but for other classes sticking with their main stat is better:

**330 [Main Stat]** and **200 Vitality** vs. **330 Vitality** and **200 [Main Stat]**.

Which plan provides the most optimal stat distribution for each piece of armor (including amulets) for each class?

Comment: That would depend on your build, wouldn't it?  Mostly, you'd just be looking for Main stat, Vit, crit chance + damage, and IAS.  Resists and all resist are gravy on top of that.

Comment: That is true. DPS vs. EHP, and budget also play a factor, but I'm looking for the most optimal strategy for stats when craft. Lets say we are crafting a shoulder, would it be better to for a Barb to make a Vit shoulder over a Str shoulder, since shoulders can roll up to 300 Str, but less Vit than if you craft a Str Shoulder?

Comment: just keep in mind you cut your chances of getting a good roll drastically going for spaulders of vit.

Comment: The answer to this question is entirely build dependent.